# Not able to read data from firestore using schedule functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cron, google-cloud-functions

There are multiple documents in collection 'Test1'. I want to read the documents of this collection which are the objects. I could se "completeOrder?? QuerySnapshot {" in log message but not the objects.

```
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.indianTimeCrontab = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('1 16 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/Los_Angeles') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun(async () => {
    const completeOrder = await db.collection('Test1').get();
    console.log('completeOrder??', completeOrder);
    return null;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#get) method with  `await db.collection('Test1').get();` you actually get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html).

You then need to use the [`forEach()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html#forEach)  method or the [`docs`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html#docs) property of the `QuerySnapshot` in order to get the documents (i.e. the "objects").

For example, you can use `forEach()` as follows:

```
  exports.indianTimeCrontab = functions.pubsub
    .schedule('1 16 * * *')
    .timeZone('America/Los_Angeles') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
    .onRun(async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await db.collection('Test1').get();
     
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      });
      return null;
    });
```